# Shortcut to return realpath of the symlink?

Tags: shortcut-keys, symbolic-link

Is there any shortcut to return actual path of the symlink?

like : I have created a symlink in home

```
$ cd
$ ln -s /home/usr/workspace/helloworld/datadir datadir
$ ls -l

lrwxrwxrwx  1 usr usr    10 Mar  5 16:57 datadir -> /home/usr/workspace/helloworld/datadir
```

Now,

```
$ cd datadir
$ pwd
/home/usr/datadir
```

Here is there any way get back to  `/home/usr/workspace/helloworld/` directory without typing whole path

```
$ cd ../
```

This takes me back to home directory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command,

```
readlink -f $(pwd)
```

`readlink` reads the contents of a symlink, and `readlink -f` follows symlinks to symlinks to symlinks, etc., until it finds something that isn't a symlink.

So,

```
cd $(readlink -f $(pwd))
```

OR

```
cd $(readlink -f .)
```

The above commands allows you to go into the original directory.

Example,

```
~/Desktop$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 avinash avinash        22 Mar  4 14:11 Pictures -> /home/avinash/Pictures

~/Desktop$ cd Pictures
~/Desktop/Pictures$ pwd
/home/avinash/Desktop/Pictures

~/Desktop/Pictures$ readlink -f $(pwd)
/home/avinash/Pictures

~/Desktop/Pictures$ cd $(readlink -f $(pwd))
~/Pictures$
```

Comment: Thanks but not of use! I want to go back to previous directory. like `"cd .."`

Comment: Saying "not of use" isn't a very nice attitude to have to someone who spends their free time helping you. It's very much of use, because  were you to run something like `cd $(readlink -f $(pwd)) && cd ..` to first go into the "real" directory and then moving up, you would have done what you asked for (I assume). You could make it into an alias if you want to do this a lot.

Comment: don't need to run `cd ..`

Comment: Yes you do, if you want to go up one step after switching to the "real" directory that the symlink went to. (Which is what I think he asked for)

Comment: op asked " i cd into the shortcut directory.From inside that directory how do i go into the original directory by running a single command".That's it.

Comment: he also asked that when i run `$ cd ../` , it takes me to the home directory not to the original directory.

Comment: i only posted first the answer as `readlink -f $(pwd)`.So he suddenly posted the first comment like that.After that i edited my answer and added `cd $(readlink -f $(pwd))` which let him to go inside the original directory.

Comment: @bigbadonk420, Sorry about my words!

`Saying "not of use" isn't a very nice attitude to have to someone who spends their free time helping you.` 
Thanks for the line